# Regular functions on the complement of an irreducible conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $C$ be an irreducible conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (in order to fix ideas we can take $C = \mathbb{V}( x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2)$ where $x_0, x_1, x_2$ are the homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^2$. Let $X = \mathbb{P}^2 \setminus C$. We know (by using degree-2 Veronese embedding) that $X$ in an affine variety.

My porpuse is to build a regular non-constant function on X, or, more generally, compute the ring of regular function $O_{X}(X) = \mathbb{C}[X]$.

I know that such a regolar function actually exists and I know it is essentially a polinomial function. But how to be sure to do the right choice? For example, could be the function $f= x_0$ work?

I'm not sure, but $X$ should be isomorphic to $V_{2,2} \cap \mathbb{A}^5$. Is this true? ($V_{2,2} = v_2 ( \mathbb{P}^2)$)

If it is, then i can compute $V_{2,2} \cap \mathbb{A}^5$ as the zero locus of an ideal by substituting $a_0 = 1$ in the equations of $V_{2,2}$ if we denote $a_i$ the homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^5$. Let me call $I$ this ideal. Then i can compute "easly" $\mathbb{C}[a_0, \dots, a_5] / I$. Right?

Recap:

1. Is it true that $X$ is isomorphic to $V_{2,2} \cap \mathbb{A}^5$?
2. $\mathbb{C}[a_0, \dots, a_5] / I$ is isomorphic to something easier to understand?

Comment: Your curve is $C:f(x_0,x_1,x_2)=0$ then $\Bbb{C}[\frac1{f(1,x_1/x_0,x_2/x_0)}]$ is a ring of rational functions on $\Bbb{P}^2$ regular away from $C$. If the affine algebraic set $f(1,y_1,y_2)=0$ is irreducible this is the whole ring $O_{\Bbb{P}^2}(\Bbb{P}^2-C)$

Comment: By $\mathbb{C}[\dfrac{1}{f(1,x_1/x_0,x_2/x_0)}]$ you mean polynomials $g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $x=\dfrac{1}{f(1,x_1/x_0,x_2/x_0)}$ or $\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,x_2] / \mathbb{I}(\dfrac{1}{f(1,x_1/x_0,x_2/x_0)})$?

Comment: And in which way those functions are polinomial functions as we should expect?

Comment: It means the ring $\{ \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{c_n}{f(1,x_1/x_0,x_2/x_0)^n}, c_n \in \Bbb{C}\}$.  What do you mean with "polynomial functions". The field of rational functions on $\Bbb{P}^2= \{ [x_0:x_1:x_2]\}$ is $\Bbb{C}(x_1/x_0,x_2/x_0)$. Then $u$ is regular on $\Bbb{P}^2-C,C=V(f)$ iff $Div(u)= \sum_{j=1}^m P_j - Q_j$, $Q_j \subset C$ where $P_j,Q_j$ are irreducible hypersurfaces, if $(f)$ is prime ideal then  $Q_j \subset C \implies Q_j = C$ so that $u f^m$ has no pole thus it is constant and $u \in \Bbb{C}[1/f]$.

Comment: I mean a function that can be defined by evaluating a polynomial (essentially a normal polynomial). Sorry but I stil don't know the concept of divisor $Div$. My background on algebraic geometry isn't so developed

Comment: Polynomial in what expressions, which polynomial ring. The coordinates of $\Bbb{A}^2$ become on $\Bbb{P}^2$ rational functions with poles on $\Bbb{P^2-A^2}$. And I meant $u f^m$ has poles only at the poles of $f$ so that $uf^m \in \Bbb{C}[f]$.